# How to get the name of location in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

I am new in google maps api. I want to get location name after user click to that location. I try to find answers in docs, but it so huge. Maybe someone can help to me or just say where in docs I can read about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called Reverse Geocoding, for which there is a sample in the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

That example is a simple one, which is easy to derive the main concepts from. However it gets place information from a coordinate which is typed in by the user, while you mention deriving the coordinate from a mouse click. There's an example based on mouse click here, but this example is more complex:
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html

Comment: Please could you update your example url http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html  It's not working, thanks.